# Use first argument as second argument with modifications

Tags: bash

In `bash` I am considering the log:

`atop_20210228`

Is there a way to:

`mv atop_20210228 $FIRSTARGUMENT.bkup`

So that I would be moving `atop_20210228` but just appending `.bkup` to the end?

Comment: Thanks Kamil. Yes it does: `mv atop_20210228{,.bkup}`